# JavaScript eval.call() not working properly

Tags: javascript, eval

I am currently trying to check condition strings of multiple "settings" objects in their own scope. Its probably just faster to show an example of the structure:

```
"root": {
    "Check1": {
        type: "checkbox",
        text: "test",
        value: false,
    },
    "Check2": {
        type: "checkbox",
        text: "should only show up if test is checked",
        value: false,
        condition: "Check1.value"
    }
}
```

So im using a for loop to iterate over the root-object's keys to get the child objects, then try to "eval.call()" the condition in the root object's context, like so:

```
for (var p in root) {
    var prop = root[p];
    if (prop.condition != null) {
        var result = function(str){
            return eval(str);
        }.call(root, prop.condition);

        // if result false, hide...
    }
}
```

however this will always produce an Exception like this when processing the "Check2"-element:

```
VM981:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Check1 is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (test.js:299), <anonymous>:1:1)
```

I have also tried using `eval.call(root, condition)` and `window.eval.call(root, condition)` without success.

Perhaps I've missed something but I also couldnt find very informative material on what the `.call()` function specifically does in connection with `.eval()`.

I'd appreciate any help - Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Check1` is not a standalone variable name, it's a property, so `Check1.value` (whether in `eval` or not) won't work.

Comment: Even if your "this" scope would be the "root" object?

Comment: Yes, whatever `this` is does not introduce new variables into a scope.

Comment: Ok I see, then is there another way to achieve what I want in js? Since I'm actually using an existing format where this is a feature...

Comment: Could you just change the `condition` string to refer to `root.Check1.value` instead?

Comment: Since you are passing `root` into `call()` you could use  `condition: "this.Check1.value"` Alternatively you could append `this`: `return eval('this.'+str);`

Comment: Using `eval()` is also a bad idea. It would be better to store a function in the `condition` property, and then call the function.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however modifying the condition string is a bit out of question since Im actually working with existing files in the mentioned format. So I cant put a function there aswell. Also: there can be multiple condition checks like eg "Check1.value && Check2.value"which makes it hard to just put ´this.´ in front